# How can I make a copy of a folder in a website?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-4.0, visual-web-developer-2010

I have a couple of web pages in a folder, and want to copy the folder to have a set of similar pages (with only a couple of changes).

However, when I simply copy and paste it in Visual Web Developer I get errors:

> Type 'WebApplication1.Folder1.WebForm1' already defines a member
>   called 'Page_Load' with the same parameter types

And:

> The type 'WebApplication1.Folder1.WebForm1' already contains a
>   definition for 'form1'

So how do I make a copy, where the namespace or class name isn't *exactly* the same - Is there a way to let Visual Studio do it for me? If not - What should I change to have it work but not break the code?

EDIT:

Here's what I did:

1. New project
2. Asp.net web application
3. Added folder to project
4. Added webform to folder
5. Folder right-click copy
6. Project right-click paste
7. F5
8. Got errors

Answer (score 2):

In the copied folder, you have to change a few things.

1. in the copied version WebForm1.aspx.cs code behind, change the namespace to something new. From  **namespace WebApplication1.Folder1** to **namespace WebApplication1.NewFolder1**
2. in the markup of WebForm1.aspx of the copied file, you need to change the "inherits" property of the page.  It should change from  **Inherits="WebApplication1.Folder1.WebForm1"** to **Inherits="WebApplication1.NewFolder1.WebForm1"**.
3. you should change the namespace in any of file that was copied over as well, but if you just have an empty webform, then the first 2 steps should get you going.

There might be an automatic way to do all of this, (find and replace could work, or some other VS feature) , but i don't know about it.

Comment: The designer file has to be changed as well. Perhaps something else too?